# Block Diagonal Covariance Matrix for GMM using scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gmm

I am trying to implement SCGMM which incorporates spatial and color features in one GMM. Most of the papers have used decoupled covariance matrices. But in the SCIKIT Learn Mixture Library, there is no option to have block diagonal covariance matrix type. Can anyone help?